# Do there exist a nontrivial group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{Z},+)?$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

**My Thought:**

Let $\phi:\mathbb{Q}^* \to \mathbb{Z}$ be a nontrivial homomorphism. Then I have observed the following properties:

1. $\phi(p^n)=n\cdot\phi(p) \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. $\phi(p^{-n})=n\cdot\phi(p^{-1}) \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So $\phi$ can be completely determined by its values in $p$ and $p^{-1}$ for all prime $p$.

Is there some other direction to think and get some thing else? Please provide me some hints. Thank you.

Comment: And also $\phi(p^{-1})=-\phi(p)$.

Comment: What would $\phi(pq)$ be for distinct primes $p,q?$

Comment: See also here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207045/number-of-homomorphisms-from-q-to-z and here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223091/non-trivial-homomorphism-between-multiplicative-group-of-rationals-and-integers

Comment: $\mathbb Q^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not quite. What element of $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ corresponds to $(1, 1, 1, ...)$?

Comment: Yeah, got a head of myself, the homeomorphisms of $\mathbb Q^{\times}\to\mathbb Z$, under addition, is a geoup  isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}.$ @MarkSaving

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good point. I have included a brief proof of this fact in my answer.

Comment: This has been asked 3 times in the past 24hrs

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are nontrivial group homomorphisms. In fact, they can be nicely classified.

Consider the function $\phi_2 : \mathbb{Q}^* \to \mathbb{Z}$, where $\phi_2(q)$ is defined as the unique integer such that $q \cdot 2^{- \phi_2(q)}$ can be written as $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a, b$ odd.

Then $\phi_2$ is a group homomorphism.

Note that it's possible to generalise $\phi_2$ to $\phi_p$ for any prime number $p$. So this gives us a broad class of nontrivial group homomorphisms.

In fact, it can be shown that any group homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}^* \to \mathbb{Z}$ must be of the form $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n \phi_{p_n}$, where $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence of prime numbers and $a_n$ is a sequence of integers. Note that this infinite sum makes sense because when we compute $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n \phi_{p_n}(a / b)$, only finitely many values $\phi_{p_n}(a/b)$ are nonzero.

With some more analysis, it turns out that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}) \oplus \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$, where the injections send the nontrivial element of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to $-1$ and the $n$th injection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}^*$ sends $i$ to $(p_n)^i$. This makes classifying the group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}^*$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ quite simple, since we have

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Hom(\mathbb{Q}^*, \mathbb{Z})
&\simeq Hom((\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}) \oplus \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \\
&\simeq Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \times Hom(\bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \\
&\simeq Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \times \prod\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Hom(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

and since $Hom(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq 0$, and since $Hom(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, we see that the final term is isomorphic to $\prod\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is $\phi_2$ a map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}^*$?

Comment: @Saikat Sorry, $\phi_2$ actually goes in the opposite direction $\phi_2 : \mathbb{Q}^* \to \mathbb{Z}$. I have edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: While defining $\phi_2$ you have used a function $\phi$. Can you please tell me the definition of $\phi?$

Comment: @Saikat I originally just wrote $\phi$ because I was only trying to define 1 homomorphism. This was before I decided to give a more general answer. When I was editing the answer, I didn't flip the $\phi$ to a $\phi_2$. But that typo has now been fixed.

Comment: @Saikat In order to "properly" define $\phi_2$, you would need to prove that for all $q \in \mathbb{Q^*}$, there exists a unique $n$ such that $q \cdot 2^{-n}$ can be written as $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b$ are both odd. Once you do this, you can define $\phi_2(q)$ to be that specific $n$. So yes, I did not completely fill in the steps of defining $\phi_2$. But if you know a bit about prime factorisations, it should be a pretty simple proof.

Comment: Can you please help me understand the function $\phi_2$ by giving some example? For example what is $\phi_2(1/2)?$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127923/discussion-between-mark-saving-and-saikat).